# What are these different errors I'm getting when scraping using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, html-table, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape this site called [whoscored.com](https://whoscored.com) and here's the simple code I'm using to scrape a particular page of it.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 
           'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}
page = 
"https://www.whoscored.com/Teams/13/RefereeStatistics/England-Arsenal"

pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'lxml')
print(pageSoup)
```

The code runs just fine but here's what it's returning -

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>
<style type="text/css">

<!--

body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans- 
serif;background:#EEEEEE;}

fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 

h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}

h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 

h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 

#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font- 
family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;

background-color:#555555;}

#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}

.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin- 
top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}

-->

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
<div class="content-container"><fieldset>
<h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
<h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name 
changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
</fieldset></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
(function() {
var _analytics_scr = document.createElement('script');
_analytics_scr.type = 'text/javascript'; _analytics_scr.async = true; 
_analytics_scr.src = '/_Incapsula_Resource? 
SWJIYLWA=719d34d31c8e3a6e6fffd425f7e032f3&ns=1&cb=1578388490';
var _analytics_elem = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
_analytics_elem.parentNode.insertBefore(_analytics_scr, _analytics_elem);
})();
// ]]>
</script></body>
</html>
```

As you see, it returns `404 - file or directory not found` or `The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name 
changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`There's another bunch of error at the end which I'm not all too familiar with.

I have a few ideas why this might be happening. Maybe there's JavaScript(I see that at the end) or it's due to some sort of counter-measure by the website. However, I'd like to know exactly what's the problem and what can I do to solve this and make sure I'm getting the data I am trying to scrape from the [page](https://www.whoscored.com/Teams/13/RefereeStatistics/England-Arsenal) - which, by the way, is the entire table. 
The little I got from reading similar questions on here is that I need to use Selenium but I'm not sure how. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm on IDLE. My Python version is 37(64-bit), and my computer is 64 bit.

Comment: when I open your url from script in web browser then I also get error 404 - so your url is wrong.

Comment: the actual url is https://www.whoscored.com/Teams/13/RefereeStatistics/England-Arsenal but there does appear to be bot measures in place so check terms and conditions of the site regarding scraping.

Comment: I'll edit the question. I probably made a mistake while copying the URL apologies. Nonetheless, it still produces the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code you have `England/Arsenal` in url but it has to be `England-Arsenal` - see `/` and `-`

But page use JavaScript so using `BeautifulSoup` you can't get data. You will have to use `Selenium` to control web browser which will load page and run JavaScript. After rendering page you can get HTML from  brower (using Selenium) and use `BeautifulSoup` to search your data.

---

Get tables with Selenium and BeautifulSoup

```
import selenium.webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.whoscored.com/Teams/13/RefereeStatistics/England-Arsenal"

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
#driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

#print(driver.page_source) # HTML

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
all_tables = soup.find_all('table')
print('len(all_tables):', len(all_tables))

for table in all_tables:
    print(table)
```

Comment: Could you suggest any reading material/resource to start with Selenium?

Comment: I always use Google to find solution for some problem. You could start with official documentation for [Selenium with Python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html). There is also [Elemental Selenium](http://elementalselenium.com/) and [one tip from this page](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/36-available-resources), other [tips](http://elementalselenium.com/tips) in Archive

Comment: I put code which use Selenium+BeautifulSoup to get tables on your page.

Comment: Thank you @furas. I was in the process of writing a code myself which could help me to scrape other tables. I will go through all of the suggested links.

Comment: I have s few questions/concerns. Firstly, why can't I find all the values of the table from the HTML of the page - using  print (driver.page_source)? Is that due to the difference between dynamic/static content?   Secondly, how do I print only one table from `all_tables`? I used [:-2] but it only prints the column names. Also, I have trouble saving the resulting df to csv using the df.to_csv(). The code doesn't show any error but I can't find the .csv anywhere on my PC

Comment: there as three `<table>` so you have `all_tables[0]` , `all_tables[1]` and `all_tables[2]` - but page can use `<table>` to display different elements - ie. it may use it to display menu. Use full path in `df.to_csv('/full/path/to/file.csv')` and you will know where it should be.

Comment: using `print(driver.page_source)` you should see all HTML - HTML loaded from server + HTML created with JavaScript. But it is hard to find something on screen when it display so many HTML's tags. `driver.page_source` is a string so you can try to find something using string's function - ie. `driver.page_source.find("<table")` but with BeautifulSoup (or lxml, pyquery) it is easier to find something.